# Lambda expressions in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a table `CandidateMains` and it has a primary key `can_main_key`. I want to get the primary key and all its values in a `var`. So far done so much.

```
var candidate = db_can_records.CandidateMains.Where(m => m.can_main_key).ToList();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking? Do you just want all the data? Do you want to retrieve record of a specific key?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,No i dont want all the data i jus want the data of primary key for all the records in one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Select` instead of `Where` to get a list of all can_main_key values:

```
var candidate = db_can_records.CandidateMains.Select(m => m.can_main_key).ToList();
```

To get all the values for a single row of CandidateMains where you know the key try:

```
var candidate = db_can_records.CandidateMains.FirstOrDefault(m => m.can_main_key == variableContainingRequiredId);
```